# Defined string data from class

Tags: c#, string, class, constructor, definition

Please, can you help me how can i get data from class for second Initialize.
Problem is that for third Step is "Login" and "Password" -> Null
But i defined this "Login" and "Password" in second step. Can you tell me why is login and password for third step null and how can i fix it? I wont create static class for this.

Comment: ok wait i will add here debug

Comment: You're not using the `login` variable at all after initializing it. Think about that.

Comment: Skeet is right, I skimmed through the code too quickly. Just because you inherit from the same base does not mean that it is the same object

Comment: I added to my post debugg for login and password output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So unless I'm missing something here:

```
access.ValidateLogin(login.Login, login.Password);
```

The `login` object has the values you set during the process of getting data.

---

If you're not going to leverage the same object, and you want them the same, then I guess you'd have to do this:

```
LoginValidation access = new LoginValidation();
access.Login = login.Login;
access.Password = login.Password;
access.ValidateLogin(loginText.Text, passwordText.Text);
```

But this is really odd. It will work, but this just doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: problem is not here access.ValidateLogin(loginText.Text, passwordText.Text);

Problem is that in second step i defined Login and Password for class Collections but in third step this definion is again empty. (null)

Comment: @RadekTarant, they aren't the same instance of the object. How would the values persist, or *migrate*, between instances?

Comment: Thx for help i little edited this ´access.ValidateLogin(login.Login, login.Password);´ and now its works. THX!

Comment: @Radek, I'm glad I could be of assistance!

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on the comments for learning purposes.

```
Inheritance != Object Reference
```

Give the following:

```
public class A
{
  public String Foo;
}

public class B : A
{
  SetFoo(String foo)
  {
    Foo = foo
  }
}

public class C : A
{
  UseFoo()
  {
    PrintLn(Foo);
  }
}
```

When you create the object `B` and set `Foo`, that does not set the `Foo` in `C` simple because they both inherit from `A`. They are different objects, so have different references to their own `Foo`

So, your code could do something like this and be correct :

```
public void Main()
{
  var validLoginInfo = new LoginInfo(loginText.Text)
  var isValid = new LoginValidator(loginText.Text, passwordText.Text, validLoginInfo).Validate();
  ...
}
```

Then you can use the given values and compare to the valid login information.